# Null Values Returns 0 in Query Function Result in G-Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm doing a query function in google sheets to combine multiple tabs with the same data sets.  However, I have some cells from those tabs that really have blanks or null values and the query is returning them as 0 in the **Combined** tab. What can I do to make sure the result of the query will be as is? meaning if the cell is blank or null, it should be null as well in the combined tab, if the cell value is 0, it should be 0.

This is my query located in a tab I named **'Combined'**.

> `=QUERY({Data1!A2:FA;Data2!A3:FA;Data3!A3:FA;Data4.1!A3:FA;Data4.2!A3:FA;Data5.1!A3:FA;Data5.2!A3:FA},"Select *  where Col5 is not null ",0)`>

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: are you sure thats what really happens? your formula is correct and based on that null values are not converted to 0 anyhow. check the formating of your column

Comment: Please share a test sheet.